# Layout for small tables with large captions

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a small amount of data to put into a table but I also need to describe the experiment in the caption. So naturally the table is pretty small with a big block of text above it, which doesn't look very great in my opinion.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von $\SI{2500}{\frac{1}{min}}$, einem konstanten Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit von \SI{110}{KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11}
\vspace{2.5mm}
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Höhe bei} & \multirow{2}{*}{Benötigte Zeit [s]}\\
    Messbeginn [ft] & Messende [ft] &\\
    \midrule
    2000 & 4000 & 110\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Result of the first code sample]

So I was wondering if there's a way to make small tables look good. I used tabularx to get the tablesize to pagewidth but it makes the table look empty.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von $\SI{2500}{\frac{1}{min}}$, einem konstanten Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit von \SI{110}{KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11}
\vspace{2.5mm}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Höhe bei} & \multirow{2}{*}{Benötigte Zeit [s]}\\
    Messbeginn [ft] & Messende [ft] &\\
    \midrule
    2000 & 4000 & 110\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image: result of the second code sample]

It's a problem I stumble across fairly often and a lot of web searches didn't get me very far.

**So my Question is if there's a smart way to layout small tables with big captions.**

Comment: use the first form, looks fine to me.

Comment: I agree with @DavidCarlisle regarding the first form. However you might think of a very short caption then follow the table by an extended explanation, but this might confuse the reader.

Comment: What you also can try is to shorten the caption text itself. E.g. drop words, use shorter synonyms etc. Think of having to pay per character or having to use very limited space.

Comment: With the `caption` package, you can set the caption width and use a smaller font.

Comment: i would also suggest to move the information in the caption to the main text and use `\label`/`\ref` to to create a cross reference to the table. Another way would be to "turn" the table, i.e., two columns with the parameters left and the values right, and then use sidecaptions.

Comment: I'm also not a fan of big captions, but my last tutor was really sensible regarding captions and wanted us to describe the experiment again in the caption (for people who only look at the tables, her words, not mine). But I shortened the text and will make it smaller.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding a clip art frame around the tabular?  Or `\fbox{\fbox{\fbox{...}}}`?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the hanging format for the caption is good when captions are very long.

You have some choices. You can use the table at its natural size or widen it with `tabular*`. It mostly depends on the table contents, though. For instance, in the last example it's really too spread out. And in the second example (which is quite similar to your `tabularx` proposal) the hanging caption makes the whole thing visually unbalanced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\captionsetup{format=hang}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\DeclareSIUnit{\KIAS}{KIAS}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von 
  $\qty{2500}{\per\minute}$, einem konstanten
  Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit
  von \qty{110}{\KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das
  Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c c c@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Höhe bei} & Benötigte Zeit\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
Messbeginn (ft) & Messende (ft) & (s) \\
\midrule
2000 & 4000 & 110\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von 
  $\qty{2500}{\per\minute}$, einem konstanten
  Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit
  von \qty{110}{\KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das
  Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11-again}

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Höhe bei} & Benötigte Zeit\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
Messbeginn (ft) & Messende (ft) & (s) \\
\midrule
2000 & 4000 & 110\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von 
  $\qty{2500}{\per\minute}$, einem konstanten
  Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit
  von \qty{110}{\KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das
  Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11-againagain}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Höhe bei} & Benötigte Zeit\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
Messbeginn (ft) & Messende (ft) & (s) \\
\midrule
2000 & 4000 & 110\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach might be with `threeparttable`: it's a sort of compromise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\captionsetup{format=hang}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\DeclareSIUnit{\KIAS}{KIAS}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Bei einer konstanten Motordrehzahl von 
  $\qty{2500}{\per\minute}$, einem konstanten
  Ladedruck von \SI{25}{inHg} und einer Geschwindigkeit
  von \qty{110}{\KIAS} wird gemessen, in welcher Zeit das
  Flugzeug von einer Höhe in eine andere steigt.}
\label{tab:11}

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Höhe bei} & Benötigte Zeit\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
Messbeginn (ft) & Messende (ft) & (s) \\
\midrule
2000 & 4000 & 110\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note how to input `\per\minute`, not with a fraction.